# General-Purpose Recursive Class?

Tags: java, recursion

Im new to Stackoverflow, so I am sorry if I did not format my question correctly.

I am currently in the process of studying programming with Java and have gone as far as Advanced Trees & Graphs. I was given a task to design a "general-purpose recursive class" with a main method to call a method that accepts an integer. Then I will call the class/run the program through the interaction Pane such as below (currently using Dr.Java).

I am kinda confused on what a "general-purpose recursive class" is suppose to look like? I understand recursive methods, but not a class. I am sorry if it sounds like a silly question, but it is quite bugging me.

> java [classnameHere] 7  //Without the Brackets

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a class that has a member reference variable of its own type.You can assign object of that same class to that variable and can go deep inside to implement concepts like linked list without pointer. like,

```
class A
{
A ob;
}
```